# Android Wear Watch Face get battery percentage of Phone

Tags: java, android, android-service, wear-os

I'm developing an Android Wear Watch Face and I want to show the battery percentage of the watch and the phone. I managed to get the percentage of the Watch but I'm new to Java & Android so please go easy on me with the explaining.

```
private String getBatteryInfoPhone()
{
    float retVal = 0;

    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus =  registerReceiver(null, iFilter);

    int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);

    int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    retVal = level / (float)scale;

    return Integer.toString(Math.round(retVal)) + "%";
}
```

This is the code I have at the moment to give me the percentage of my phone. 
Please note, that this is a Watch Face, so it's a service with no Activities.

With this solution I constantly get 1% instead of the actual percentage.

Comment: Can't wait for this to come out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

will give you already value between 1 and 100, so you can plug it directly as the percentage. You don't need to divide it by the scale.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is true, but now as I take the Information from that line, I get back the percentage of my watch not of my phone.

Comment: If you want to get the battery percentage from your phone, you will need to sync this information using the `DataApi`. So, read the value the same way from the mobile module and then sync it to the watch. Here is the link about the api http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html